# How to include goroutine into a context?

Tags: go, anonymous-function, goroutine, go-context

I'm working on a Go project that require calling an initiation function (`initFunction`) in a separated goroutine (to ensure this function does not interfere with the rest of the project). `initFunction`  must not take more than 30 seconds, so I thought I would use context.WithTimeout. Lastly, `initFunction` must be able to notify errors to the caller, so I thought of making an error channel and calling initFunction from an anonymous function, to recieve and report the error.

```
func RunInitGoRoutine(initFunction func(config string)error) error {

    initErr := make(chan error)
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 30*time.Seconds)

    go func() {
        <-ctx.Done()  // Line 7
        err := initFunction(config)
        initErr <-err
    }()

    select {
    case res := <-initErr:
        return res.err
    case <-ctx.Done():
        err := errors.New("Deadline")
    return err
    }
}
```

I'm quite new to Go, so I'm asking for feedbacks about the above code.

1. I have some doubt about Line 7. I used this to ensure the anonymous function is "included" under `ctx` and is therefore killed and freed and everything once timeout expires, but I'm not sure I have done the right thing.
2. Second thing is, I know I should be calling `cancel( )` somewhere, but I can't put my finger around where.
3. Lastly, really any feedback is welcome, being it about efficency, style, correctness or anything.

Comment: What your anonymous function does right now is wait 30 seconds, then run `initFunction`, which is not the desired behavior you described. There is no way to kill a goroutine from outside the function; if `initFunction` needs to timeout after 30 seconds, that *must* be implemented *inside* `initFunction`, which must take the context as a parameter.

Comment: It's a common mistake in Go in thinking that `context.Context` does some magic. You have a requirement about `initFunction` and how much time it takes. The fulfillment of that requirement has all to do with the implementation of `initFunction` (which we can't see).

Comment: So if the second case of the select is reached (which means 30s are elapsed) `RunInitGoRoutine` will return but the goroutine and the anonymous function inside it will be kept alive?

Comment: Yes. Again: There is no magic on Go. A contect.Context does literally _nothing_ in regard to execution. Really. Anything you want to happen must be provided by code you write e.g. by using a Context. If initFunction is not _designed_ to be aborted there is no way (except terminating the whole program) to kill it from the outside.

Comment: You need your initFunction to take a context value, and handle its own termination when that context is cancelled.

Comment: Others have pointed out that your routine is essentially waiting for the context to expire. In addition to that, I'd like to add 2 comments: your last `return err` is not indented properly, and you can just write `return errors.New()` instead of assigning it to `err` first. The error itself should also not start with an upper-case letter (golang code review)

Answer (score 0):

In Go the pratice is to communicate via channels. So best thing is probably to share a channel on your context so others can consume from the channel.

As you are stating you are new to Go, I wrote a whole bunch of articles on Go (Beginner level) https://marcofranssen.nl/categories/golang.

Read from old to new to get familiar with the language.

Regarding the channel specifics you should have a look at this article.

https://marcofranssen.nl/concurrency-in-go

A pratical example of a webserver listening for `ctrl+c` and then gracefully shutting down the server using channels is described in this blog post.

https://marcofranssen.nl/improved-graceful-shutdown-webserver

In essence we run the server in a background routine

```golang
go func() {
    if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
      srv.l.Fatal("Could not listen on", zap.String("addr", srv.Addr), zap.Error(err))
    }
  }()
```

and then we have some code that is blocking the main routine by listening on a channel for the shutdown signal.

```golang
quit := make(chan os.Signal, 1)

  signal.Notify(quit, os.Interrupt)
  sig := <-quit
  srv.l.Info("Server is shutting down", zap.String("reason", sig.String()))

  ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 30*time.Second)
  defer cancel()

  srv.SetKeepAlivesEnabled(false)
  if err := srv.Shutdown(ctx); err != nil {
    srv.l.Fatal("Could not gracefully shutdown the server", zap.Error(err))
  }
  srv.l.Info("Server stopped")
```

This is very similar to your usecase. So running your init in a background routine and then consume the channel waiting for the result of this init routine.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type InitResult struct {
    Message string
}

func main() {
    initResult := make(chan InitResult, 0)
    go func(c chan<- InitResult) {
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        // here we are publishing the result on the channel
        c <- InitResult{Message: "Initialization succeeded"}
    }(initResult)

    fmt.Println("Started initializing")

    // here we have a blocking operation consuming the channel
    res := <-initResult

    fmt.Printf("Init result: %s", res.Message)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/_YGIrdNVZx6

You could also add an error field on the struct so you could do you usual way of error checking.